# Woocommerce - Not to show variable price range

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have been searching for a while but have yet been able to get a perfect solution without messing things up...

All I wanted to do is to remove the variable price range (i.e., area A) and move the product specific price (i.e., area B) to area A.

I also wanted to keep the original area A font size to the product specific price.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this tuts ? https://learnwoo.com/hide-price-range-woocommerce-variable-products/